# Espresso how to test button not enabled until 9 digits are entered

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I am having problems testing my app.I am not new to testing but alot changes in our industry it is hard to keep up. I have this `edittext` that requires 9 numeric digits for the button start to be clicked, how can I test the button being disabled in espresso until the 9 numeric are entered?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `Enabled` status of the button after entering the text in the `EditText` by using:

`onView(withId(R.id.yourButtonId)).check(matches(isEnabled()))`

Or you can also check whether it is disabled by using:

`onView(withId(R.id.categoryContinueBtn)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())))`